# Convert single Latex strings into normal text

Tags: command-line, bash, latex

I want to use a bash script to extract Author and Title from a latex file and save it in a variable, I found a solution, however if the title or the names use a special character (like \'e) it will also be saved. Here my question: Is there a command to convert this format into normal or a different way that's easier?
Here my solution for the problem:

```
Author=`grep -r "\\\author" $File | head -1 | cut -d'{' -f2 | cut -d'}' -f1`
Title=`grep -r "\\\title" $File | head -1 |cut -d'{' -f2 | cut -d'}' -f1`
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Interesting Q (although you might get more response on tex.stackexchange.com - see for example [Auto convert LaTeX escape codes to UTF-8 characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165170/auto-convert-latex-escape-codes-to-utf-8-characters/165187#165187)). A bit of googling turns up that emacs has a `M-x iso-tex2iso` that (for example) converts `\'e` to é and can apparently be run in batch mode [How to run iso-tex2iso in batch mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7782)